# read string by white spaces in php

Tags: php, laravel-5, pdf-reader, pdfparser

i an trying to read a PDF with this library `\Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();` in `laravel 5.6`

I am getting all content ok, but i have this:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  MARTIN CARRILLO MARIA ESMERALDA ALHAMBRA 10 958 54 38 93
    [1] =>  ESPIGARES DIAS JOSE ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 11 958 54 33 32
    [2] =>  GUTIERREZ TITOS JOSE MANUEL ALHAMBRA 12 958 54 04 10
    [3] =>  MARTIN COBOS ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 18 958 54 33 28
    [4] =>  GOMEZ CARRILLO JOSE ALHAMBRA 20 958 54 32 72
    [5] =>  RODRIGUEZ RUANO BUENAVENTURA ALHAMBRA 21 958 54 35 86
    [6] =>  GARCIA ARIAS MARIA ISABEL ALHAMBRA 22 958 54 07 87
    [7] =>  RODRIGUEZ JIMENEZ MIGUEL ALHAMBRA 27 958 54 08 77
    [8] =>  GUTIERREZ FERNANDEZ AMANDA HILDA ALHAMBRA 3 958 49 98 62
    [9] =>  DIAZ FLORIAN DOLORES ALHAMBRA 30 958 54 33 99
    [10] =>  PEREZ LASTRA SAUL ADAN ALHAMBRA 32 958 54 31 46
    [11] =>  AMIGO MOLINA MARIA MATILDE ALHAMBRA 35 958 54 31 91
    [12] =>  ESPIGARES GOMEZ JORGE ALHAMBRA 37 958 54 02 22
    [13] =>  ESPIGARES ESPIGARES JOSE ALHAMBRA 40 958 54 31 83
```

but I need to get the second surname, surname, name, address and phone from these strings... I think that I can get all data count white spaces.

I am trying this:

```
// loop to get data line
foreach($dataByLine as &$line){      
    // delete first element in string
    $cleanString = substr($line, 0, 7);
    $line = str_replace($cleanString, "", $line);   
    
    $line = preg_replace('/^[\d]+/','',$line);
    //$line = ltrim($line,"0123456789");
    $stringDivide = preg_split('/\s+/', $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    
    //array_push($secondSurnameArray, $stringDivide[0]);

    array_push($dataList, $line);
}

print_r($dataList);
```

but this return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MARTIN
    [1] => CARRILLO
    [2] => MARIA
    [3] => ESMERALDA
    [4] => ALHAMBRA
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 958
    [7] => 54
    [8] => 38
    [9] => 93
)
Array
(
    [0] => ESPIGARES
    [1] => DIAS
    [2] => JOSE
    [3] => ANTONIO
    [4] => ALHAMBRA
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 958
    [7] => 54
    [8] => 33
    [9] => 32
)
Array
(
    [0] => GUTIERREZ
    [1] => TITOS
    [2] => JOSE
    [3] => MANUEL
    [4] => ALHAMBRA
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 958
    [7] => 54
    [8] => 04
    [9] => 10
)
```

for example, but if i do this:

```
array_push($secondSurnameArray, $stringDivide[0]);
```

this return that index 0 it´s not defined.

I need this data to create one array to create insert query.

Thanks for help me, read me and sorry for my english.

**update**

i hope this:

```
$secondSurname = ['MARTIN', 'ESPIGARES', 'GUTIERREZ'....etc]
$surname = ['CARRILLO', 'DIAS', 'TITOS', .....etc]
$name = ['JOSE', 'JOSE', 'ANTONIO']
$addres = ['ALHAMBRA 10', 'ALHAMBRA 11', 'ALHAMBRA 12', etc]
$phone = ['958 54 38 93', '958 54 33 32', '958 54 04 10']
```

after i need to do array merge with `$secondSurname, $surname and $name` to do insert query

Comment: What expected output you want? Show a sample of your expected outcome.

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh thanks for your response. I update my question with mi hope return

Comment: Impossible to do because no fix pattern like which data will go to name,surnmae,secondSurname.  like in your sample output you want, for first user you are missing `MARIA ESMERALDA` ? why thse 2 got skipped? for second user `ANTONIO` is missing

Comment: Instead of using space while creating pdf, use`-` to separate values, so that when you read it then it's easy to split sting base on `-` and directly get data without any issue. example :`MARTIN-CARRILLO MARIA ESMERALDA-ALHAMBRA 10-958 54 38 93`

Comment: @AnantKumarSigh thanks for your response. it´s example, I need also Maria, Esmeralda... etc i forget etc

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh i can´t to do this.. Because this PDFs it´s generated, only i´m using it

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh if you know other form to read pdf and getting all data separated...

Comment: Can you show us the query you are trying to build the data for please

Comment: @RiggsFolly yet i don´t building my query, firt i need all my data ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to loose the additional surname if there are 2 so thats easily done in the loop.

Also merging up the parts that make up the phone number can simply be done there as well.

```
$dataByLine = [ 
    'MARTIN CARRILLO MARIA ESMERALDA ALHAMBRA 10 958 54 38 93',
    'ESPIGARES DIAS JOSE ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 11 958 54 33 32',
    'GUTIERREZ TITOS JOSE MANUEL ALHAMBRA 12 958 54 04 10',
    'MARTIN COBOS ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 18 958 54 33 28',
    'GOMEZ CARRILLO JOSE ALHAMBRA 20 958 54 32 72',
    'RODRIGUEZ RUANO BUENAVENTURA ALHAMBRA 21 958 54 35 86',
    'GARCIA ARIAS MARIA ISABEL ALHAMBRA 22 958 54 07 87',
    'RODRIGUEZ JIMENEZ MIGUEL ALHAMBRA 27 958 54 08 77',
    'GUTIERREZ FERNANDEZ AMANDA HILDA ALHAMBRA 3 958 49 98 62',
    'DIAZ FLORIAN DOLORES ALHAMBRA 30 958 54 33 99',
    'PEREZ LASTRA SAUL ADAN ALHAMBRA 32 958 54 31 46',
    'AMIGO MOLINA MARIA MATILDE ALHAMBRA 35 958 54 31 91',
    'ESPIGARES GOMEZ JORGE ALHAMBRA 37 958 54 02 22',
    'ESPIGARES ESPIGARES JOSE ALHAMBRA 40 958 54 31 83'
];

$secondSurname  = [];
$surname        = [];
$name           = [];
$address        = [];
$phone          = [];

foreach($dataByLine as $line){      
    $t = explode(' ', $line);   # make array from string using space as seperator
    // fix double surname issue
    if ( count($t) == 10 ){
        // we have a line with a double surname
        array_shift($t);   # drop the first name in list
    }
    $secondSurname[]    = $t[0];
    $surname[]          = $t[1];
    $name[]             = $t[2];
    $address[]          = $t[3];
    $phone[]            = $t[4] . $t[5] . $t[6] . $t[7] . $t[8]; 
    # you can add space and or `-` into the phone if you like
}

echo 'SecondSurnames ';
print_r($secondSurname);
echo 'Surnames ';
print_r($surname);
echo 'names ';
print_r($name);
echo 'address ';
print_r($address);
echo 'phone ';
print_r($phone);
```

RESULTS

```
SecondSurnames Array
(
    [0] => CARRILLO
    [1] => DIAS
    [2] => TITOS
    [3] => MARTIN
    [4] => GOMEZ
    [5] => RODRIGUEZ
    [6] => ARIAS
    [7] => RODRIGUEZ
    [8] => FERNANDEZ
    [9] => DIAZ
    [10] => LASTRA
    [11] => MOLINA
    [12] => ESPIGARES
    [13] => ESPIGARES
)
Surnames Array
(
    [0] => MARIA
    [1] => JOSE
    [2] => JOSE
    [3] => COBOS
    [4] => CARRILLO
    [5] => RUANO
    [6] => MARIA
    [7] => JIMENEZ
    [8] => AMANDA
    [9] => FLORIAN
    [10] => SAUL
    [11] => MARIA
    [12] => GOMEZ
    [13] => ESPIGARES
)
names Array
(
    [0] => ESMERALDA
    [1] => ANTONIO
    [2] => MANUEL
    [3] => ANTONIO
    [4] => JOSE
    [5] => BUENAVENTURA
    [6] => ISABEL
    [7] => MIGUEL
    [8] => HILDA
    [9] => DOLORES
    [10] => ADAN
    [11] => MATILDE
    [12] => JORGE
    [13] => JOSE
)
address Array
(
    [0] => ALHAMBRA
    [1] => ALHAMBRA
    [2] => ALHAMBRA
    [3] => ALHAMBRA
    [4] => ALHAMBRA
    [5] => ALHAMBRA
    [6] => ALHAMBRA
    [7] => ALHAMBRA
    [8] => ALHAMBRA
    [9] => ALHAMBRA
    [10] => ALHAMBRA
    [11] => ALHAMBRA
    [12] => ALHAMBRA
    [13] => ALHAMBRA
)
phone Array
(
    [0] => 10958543893
    [1] => 11958543332
    [2] => 12958540410
    [3] => 18958543328
    [4] => 20958543272
    [5] => 21958543586
    [6] => 22958540787
    [7] => 27958540877
    [8] => 3958499862
    [9] => 30958543399
    [10] => 32958543146
    [11] => 35958543191
    [12] => 37958540222
    [13] => 40958543183
)
```

> NOTE: I am not sure these seperate arrays are really the best solution to be passed to your query binding, which is why I asked to see the query.
> It may make more sence to have a single array with one occurance for each person.

Comment: Ok, last fix I think

Comment: @scorpions78  in your proposed solution you said `'ALHAMBRA 10,ALHAMBRA 12...`etc. And now the current solution is perfect for you. Kindly take care in near future that don't mislead people, give them accurate details otherwise you will not get proper solution